# UICollectionView PrepareForSegue Image not Transferring

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, storyboard, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that I cannot get to transfer the image to the detailview.  The detailview transfer would work when I used local images and the pictures array with the [pictures[row]] method, but since using the SDWebImage framework, I cannot do that.  I cannot figure out to properly transfer the image to the detail view once the cell is selected.  The logic is explained in the first method CellForItemAtIndexPath.  The selected cell and prepare for segue methods are causing the issue.  Let me know if you need more information.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    pictureViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *pictures1 = [[pictures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"filename"];
    comment = [[pictures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"comment"];

    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pictures1]
                    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Earth.png"]
    completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType)
     {
         NSLog(@"Error downloaidng images");
     }];


   // UIImage *image;

   // int row = [indexPath row];

    //image = [UIImage imageNamed:pictures[row]];

    //image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageUrl];

   // cell.imageView.image = image;

    return cell;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UIImage *image;

    //int row = [indexPath row];

    NSString *pictures1 = [[pictures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"filename"];
   // image = [UIImage imageNamed:pictures[row]];

    image = [UIImage imageNamed:pictures1];

    pictureDetailView *pictureDetail = [[pictureDetailView alloc]init];
    pictureDetail.image = image;

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UICollectionViewCell *)sender
{
    pictureDetailView *targetVC = (pictureDetailView *) [segue destinationViewController];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:sender];

    UIImage *image;

    //int row = [indexPath row];


    NSString *pictures1 = [[pictures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"filename"];


   // image = [UIImage imageNamed:pictures[row]];

    image = [UIImage imageNamed:pictures1];

    //image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageUrl];

    targetVC.image=image;
}




@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue in an app I'm working on, and could not find any help for Collection Views. The code I used is below (updated to match your methods). I hope this helps get you on the right track. You can also check the demo project posted on the [SDWebImage GitHub page](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). That helped me figure some of these issues out.

### In Your CollectionViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PictureDetailView.h"

@class PictureDetailView;

@interface CollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) PictureDetailView *detailViewController;

@end
```

### In Your CollectionViewController.m:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"yourSegueNameHere"]) {
        PictureDetailView *pictureDetail = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] lastObject];
        NSString *largeImageURL = [pictures1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        pictureDetail.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:largeImageURL];
    }
}
```

### In Your DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CollectionViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController 

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *imageURL;

@end
```

### In Your DetailViewController.m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize imageURL = _imageURL;
@synthesize imageView = _imageView;


- (void)setImageURL:(NSURL *)imageURL
{
    if (_imageURL != imageURL)
    {
        _imageURL = imageURL;
        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    if (self.imageURL)
    {
        [self.imageView setImageWithURL:self.imageURL
                       placeholderImage:nil
                        options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload
                        completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType)
         {
         }];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self configureView];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just access the `imageView` of the selected cell and extract its image. Here is how to do it:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self collectionView:collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImage *image = cell.imageView.image;

    // Pass the image to the next VC.
}
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: This method says the imageView in cell.imageView.image property was not found on object type UICollectionViewCell.